# How to join with group by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

**TableA**

```
Custid prodid Amt1
  1      10   200
  2      20   300
  3      10   400
  4      30   300
  5      20   400
  6      30   200
```

**TableB**

```
prodid  Amt2
    10   100
    20   200
    30   300
```

and I want to sum of all amount group by prodid. Can anyone give me both ansi and Tsql queries?

Comment: What have you gotten so far? Post your code before asking people to solve all of your problems for you.

Comment: Why do want ANSI _and_ T-SQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.prodid,sum(a.Amt1 + b.Amt2) as AmtSum 
     FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b ON (a.prodid = b.prodid) 
     GROUP BY a.prodid;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that? :-)

> SELECT SUM(a.Amt1),SUM(b.Amt2)
>   FROM (TableA AS a INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON
>   a.prodid = b.prodid)
>   GROUP BY a.prodid

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work anywhere:

```
SELECT a.Custid,a.prodid,sum(a.Amt1 + b.Amt2) as AmtSum FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b ON (a.prodid = b.prodid) GROUP BY a.Custid,a.prodid;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this... I think it will also work if some product id not in TABLEB

```
SELECT a.prodid,SUM(a.Amt1),SUM(b.Amt2)
FROM TableA AS a left outer JOIN TableB AS b ON a.prodid = b.prodid
GROUP BY a.prodid
```